# Select and unselect multiple days in fullcalendar monthly view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, multi-select

I am working on an application which has a requirement of selecting multiple days at a time and getting the value of that on button click and insert it into data base.

Below is my code i am using to achieve this. But i am able to do so.
Can any one help me out with this?

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month'
                },
                // defaultDate: CurrentDate[0] + "/01/" + CurrentDate[1],
                navLinks: true,
                editable: true,
                draggable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: message.ResponseData,
                selectable: true,
                select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        rendering: 'background',
                        //block: true,
                    },]);
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
                },
                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                    $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
                    $(jsEvent.target).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
                },
                selectOverlap: function (event) {
                    return !event.block;
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just send the date into the database on dayclick? Or, put the dates clicked into an array and then post all the dates in the array on the button click? You can also set a boolean value for each date to check if it has been previously selected.